# Invalid buffer pointer from MPI_Recv when sending an array

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

When running my OpenMPI program, I get the error at the bottom of this post. Specifically, it is the `MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer` error caused by an `MPI_Recv` operation that is causing trouble.

My code is rather lengthy, but I believe the error occurs when I call:

```
MPI_Recv(WTVblock, n_comp * bs_cols, MPI_DOUBLE, i, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

`WTVblock` is a double array of size `n_comp * bs_cols`. The rest of the code can be found on https://github.com/olavurmortensen/distributed_nmf/blob/master/main.c. The receive is on line 169 and the corresponding send is on line 164.

Error message:

```
[n-62-14-2:800] *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv
[n-62-14-2:800] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[n-62-14-2:800] *** MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer
[n-62-14-2:800] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
[n-62-14-2][[9104,1],2][btl_tcp_frag.c:215:mca_btl_tcp_frag_recv] mca_btl_tcp_frag_recv: readv failed: Connection reset by peer (104)
[n-62-14-2][[9104,1],4][btl_tcp_frag.c:215:mca_btl_tcp_frag_recv] mca_btl_tcp_frag_recv: readv failed: Connection reset by peer (104)
[n-62-14-2][[9104,1],3][btl_tcp_frag.c:123:mca_btl_tcp_frag_send] mca_btl_tcp_frag_send: writev failed: Connection reset by peer (104)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec has exited due to process rank 0 with PID 800 on
node n-62-14-2 exiting improperly. There are two reasons this could occur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.

2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"

This may have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpiexec (as reported here).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT: I am a newbie at MPI and at C, so I apologize if my question is dumb or if I am making some horrible mistakes in my code.

Comment: I don't know why, but I fixed the issue by receiving a "WTVblock_buff" array and sending the corresponding "WTVblock" array. I'll leave the question open in case anyone can explain what is happening here, but my problem is essentially fixed.

Comment: You are not allocating memory for `WTVblock` in the master rank.